# Binding data to a combo box in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table with three fields.

```
ID (key) County and Zone
1        Clare       1
2        Galway      1
3        Limerick    1
4        Dublin      2
```

I want to create a combo box on a form that displays county but uses the zone as the value that I will pass into the query.

Any ideas?

Comment: combobox in where msaccess or asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're bringing in all 3 fields, you would reference it by:

```
Me.ComboBox.Columns(2)
```

Controls are 0-based, so the first column is 0, the 2nd is 1 and the 3rd is 2.

You can always clean that up a bit by having the RecordSource of the combo be:

```
SELECT [Zone], [Country] from MyTable
```

Then for your column widths, set the Bound Column = "1" and the Column Widths = "0; 2" (without the quotes in both cases).  That way your users will only see the Country column, but it will pass the Zone column to your query (or whatever is referencing it).

In fact, Me.Combobox.Value would be column 0, and Me.Combobox.Text would be column 1.